# Rewrite directorys to file and after ? variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this Apache rewrite code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main\/(.*) /parser.php?folders=$1
```

But I can't access the request parameters after `?`. For example,

```
htttp://example.com/main/directry/directory2/?variable=1&error=0
```

How can i access those variables? I use PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `QSA` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /parser.php?folders=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.